# Function not getting triggered on componentWillMount when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hmmm why whenever i refresh the page validateAccount function does not run anymore?
it only runs if i navigate thru router Link

```
componentWillMount(){
    const { location, toggleGlobalHeader} = this.props;
    const userID = auth.currentUser;
    if(location.code == 404) {
        toggleGlobalHeader();
    }
    this.validateAccount(userID);
}


 validateAccount = (userObj) => {
        if(userObj){
            this.userRef.once('value').then(snap => {
                if(snap.hasChild(userObj.uid)){
                    this.getRole(userObj);
                } else {
                    this.userRef.child(userObj.uid).push({
                        email: userObj.email,
                        role: 'Member'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: did you checked `userObj ` is not coming null?

Comment: it's not coming null

Comment: if you getting not null in `validateAccount ` . during page refresh and able to . console inside it then your componentWillMount is running

Comment: i added a console.log before the if it's not running....

Comment: what is output `userObj ` inside `validateAccount ` when u refresh it

Comment: i don't know...because it's not running when i refresh it.. that's my problem..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163582/discussion-between-riyaj-khan-and-juan-dela-cruz).

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? do you mean page reload?

Comment: i fixed it i needed to use the recommended firebase listener
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, i don't think you can use `arrow` function inside class declaration. Arrow function will work inside any other function, but not inside class declaration.

Try changing it to:

```
validateAccount(userObj) {
        if(userObj){
            this.userRef.once('value').then(snap => {
                if(snap.hasChild(userObj.uid)){
                    this.getRole(userObj);
                } else {
                    this.userRef.child(userObj.uid).push({
                        email: userObj.email,
                        role: 'Member'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```